# Combination of lines from two text files

Tags: python, file, text

I have a text file `t1.txt`:

```
1¶
2¶
3
```

I have a text file `t2.txt`:

```
»1¶
»2¶
»3
```

Where `»` and `¶` represent tab and newline characters respectively.

I want to combine these two and generate all possible combinations:

```
11¶
12¶
13¶
21¶
22¶
23¶
31¶
32¶
33¶
```

Here is my code:

```
out = 'out.txt'
in1 = 't1.txt'
in2 = 't2.txt'
outFile = open(out,'w')
with open(in1, 'r') as f:
    for line1 in f:
        for line2 in open(in2, 'r'):
            outFile.write(line1+line2)
    outFile.close()
```

But the output I am getting is:

```
1¶
»1¶
1¶
»2¶
1¶
»32¶
»1¶
2¶
»2¶
2¶
»33»1¶
3»2¶
3»3
```

I do not understand why.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Hi. Look here: [iterools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and search for combinations().

Comment: you know that the indentation is incorrect?

Comment: The second `for` loop is nested inside the first which mean that it will print each line of the first file with every line of the second one, then print the second line of the first file with every line of the second, etc.

Comment: @mic4ael Yea sorry that happened while copy pasting...

Comment: @martineau why? wont it print every line of first with every line of second? 
isn't that what nested loops do? I am confused..

Comment: That's what it's doing. There's 2 issues. One is that you don't realize is that `outFile.write(line1+line2)` writes _everything_ from the first line of the first file, including any tabs, spaces, and newlines (aka whitespace characters) it contains, plus the same from the second file. The related issue is what is shown for the contents of the two files isn't quite accurate. The last line of both of them doesn't end in a newline and each line of the second one has a leading tab character in it before the number. You need to remove all this excess whitespace and add a newline to what's written.

Comment: @martineau Yea I understood.. All the whitespaces ended up confusing me.. Thank you so much for the help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are spaces and returns in your files. Trim them using strip()

```
   out = 'out.txt'
   in1 = 't1.txt'
   in2 = 't2.txt'
   outFile = open(out,'w')
   with open(in1, 'r') as f:
       for line1 in f:
           for line2 in open(in2, 'r'):
               outFile.write(line1.strip()+line2.strip()+"\n")
   outFile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :D
This was quick and easy.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You want the [product](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
f1,f2 = "123","123"
from itertools import product

print(list(product(*(f1, f2))))
```

So for your files:

```
with open("a.txt") as f1, open("b.txt") as f2:
    print(list(product(*(map(str.rstrip,f1), map(str.rstrip,f2)))))
```

Which will give you:

```
[('1', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2'), ('3', '3')]
```

And to join:

```
 print(list(map("".join, product(*(map(str.rstrip,f1), map(str.rstrip,f2))))))
['11', '12', '13', '21', '22', '23', '31', '32', '33']
```

To write to your file::

```
with open("a.txt") as f1, open("b.txt") as f2, open("out.txt", "w") as out:
    for p in product(*(map(str.rstrip,f1), map(str.rstrip, f2))):
        out.write("".join(p) + "\n")
```

Output:

```
11
12
13
21
22
23
31
32
33
```

For python2 use `itertools.imap`:

```
product(*(imap(str.rstrip,f1),imap(str.rstrip, f2))
```

Comment: How do I do this if I take input from two BIG text files? 
I want to combine lines.. from the two files...

Comment: @418, I will edit but you just apply the same logic on the files

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your lines contain newline-character and spaces. These are not visible at the end of a line.

You have to clear these characters:

```
out = 'out.txt'
in1 = 't1.txt'
in2 = 't2.txt'
with open(in2, 'r') as f:
    lines2 = [l.rstrip() for l in f]
with open(out,'w') as outFile:
    with open(in1, 'r') as f:
        for line1 in f:
            line1 = line1.rstrip()
            for line2 in lines2:
                outFile.write(line1+line2+'\n')
```